# Dataframe, Sum, Mean Help: How to sum and mean matrix?

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, mean

I need explanation for data frame, sum, and mean commands If the code below is operated, I can get list of data files `Preplist`. Yet, the commands I need explanations for does not work due to some errors.

My guess is that the data I load does not have data frame, but just list of numbers for each data file. To sum or take mean for each data file, I need data frame. (When I check number of rows there is nothing, but NULL).

I think I need to make data frame for loaded data (200x200 matrix), and also first row and column has to ignored in original data.

This is my code:

```
Prepfiles <- list.files(pattern=".csv")
Preplist <- lapply(Prepfiles, read.table, sep = '\t', 
                  na.string = '', header = TRUE, skip=1)
bigPreplist <- do.call(rbind, Preplist)
```

I need to do load data at once, and plot data (sum every three data files together, and plot). However, I have trouble to run command `sum()` and `mean()` with my `Preplist[1:24]`

I am using are all numeric in 200 by 200 matrix. There are 24 data files. Also I want to keep 200 by 200 matrix form when I load data, but with my coding, there is are no number of rows if I check with `nrow(Preplist[1])` Is it possible to keep same dataframe when you load data in? Or do I have to make new data frame?

Here are errors that I get with sum and mean commands:

```
> nrow(Preplist)
NULL
> sum(Preplist[1])
Error in sum(Preplist[1]) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
> mean(Preplist[1])
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(Preplist[1]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: Have you tried subsetting with `[[` instead of `[`?

Comment: What do you expect to be contained in `Preplist[1]`? A column of data? A 200x200 data frame?

Comment: If I can data as matrix 200 by 200, it is easier, but it can be list. I need to load numbers from data files, and take sum, mean, and plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useful here to look at the help for `[` and `[[` (which are the same page)

To quote the relevant section (as `prepList` is a list)

> #### Recursive (list-like) objects
>
> Indexing by [ is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the specified element(s).
>
> Both [[ and $ select a single element of the list. The main difference is that $ does not allow computed indices, whereas [[ does. x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]. Also, the partial matching behavior of [[ can be controlled using the exact argument.

So,

```
prepList[1]
```

selects a list of length 1. The first element of this list would be your `data.frame`

```
preplist[[1]]
```

will select the first element of `prepList` which is the data.frame you want.

That being said, I'm not sure you really want to be taking the mean or sum of a `data.frame`, you would want to make sure these returned what you wanted.

eg

```
prepList <- list(data.frame(a=1:5,b=2:6), data.frame(a=2:6,b=1:5))

# this will give a warning
mean(prepList[[1]])

## a b 
## 3 4 
## Warning message:
## mean(<data.frame>) is deprecated.
## Use colMeans() or sapply(*, mean) instead. 


## this will give a single number

sum(prepList[[1]])

## 35
```

If you want the column means for each data.frame that is in `prepList` or sums of each column use `colMeans`, `colSums`, or a nested version of `lapply` with means,

```
eg 
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(prepList, function(x) lapply(x, mean)))

##    a b
## 1: 3 4
## 2: 4 3
```

or using `plyr` and `ldply`

```
library(plyr)
 ldply(prepList, function(x) {sapply(x, mean)})
```

or to limit yourself to numeric columns

using plyr

```
ldply(prepList,  numcolwise(mean))
```

using Filter

```
rbindlist(lapply(prepList, function(x) lapply(Filter(is.numeric,x), mean)))
```

Comment: I get bunch of numbers with errors. 
> sum(Preplist[[1]])
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

>mean(Preplist[[1]])
X1.3.79.3.79.2.33.….3.87.4.01.4.01
NA 
Warning messages:
1: mean(<data.frame>) is deprecated.
 Use colMeans() or sapply(*, mean) instead. 
2: In mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: @Uka, That message is pretty self explanatory. You have non-numeric columns (not clear from your question), however I will edit my answer to filter for these.

Comment: @Uka, `skip` is an argument to `read.table` stating how many lines to skip (if any). It isn't an argument for `mean` or `sum`. I think perhaps you should read a basic introduction to R (see the wiki page here for ideas there), and perhaps read the help files for the functions your are trying to use.